# list of ALL privileges in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there somewhere in the Snowflake docs that lists the privileges whenever we grant `ALL`?

For example:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON MY_DB.MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE TO ROLE MY_ROLE
```

The following privileges would show in `SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.GRANTS_TO_ROLES` as:

- `APPLYBUDGET, DELETE, EVOLVE SCHEMA ,INSERT, REBUILD, REFERENCES, SELECT, TRUNCATE, UPDATE`

I am looking for the privileges for `SCHEMA` and `DATABASE` whenever we grant all.

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at the [Snowflake docs](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-access-control-privileges). It mentions that the ALL keyword will grant all privileges for the specified object type. So the privileges list will change according to what you are granting on. You can see in that same docs what privileges are applied to what object.

Answer (score 0):

To list all the privileges granted to the role "MY_ROLE", you can use the below query

```
show grants to role MY_ROLE;
```

You can use the RESULT_SCAN function to filter based on database/schema

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID())) where name ilike '%<Database name>%'
```